# python.. 64bit to 32bit and module problem

Tags: python, pyqt, 32bit-64bit, xlsxwriter

So, i developed a small python program with my machine.. I use some libraries like PyQt5 xlsxwriter.. Now, i get my exe with pyinstaller, but i discovered that users machine have 32bit system.. With vscode i easily change the python interpreter to rebuild with py 3.8 32 bit, but in this way, i have a error with the module import: Both PyQt5 and xlsxwriter are impossible to found.. I try to unistall e install it again, but never. I certainly wrong somthing but my basket of ideas isover..
Sorry for my English

Good day evryone!

Comment: If you install 32-bit Python, then you need to re-install all of the packages you use, and you must use the proper copy of `pip`.  This is why many people suggest using `python2 -m pip install xxxx`, so you get the same Python you'll ship with.

Comment: Are you quite sure about your requirements?  Except for hermits and a few industrial systems, there are very, very few 32-bit Windows systems left in the world today.

Comment: Hi Tim, thank for the answer.. Unfortunately im sure about requirements.. It's for old computer.. very old..